# Quarkus native image: postgresql connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, quarkus, graalvm-native-image, quarkus-panache

I created a quarkus application with access to a postgresql database on localhost. After creating the native image I try to run the application with:

docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 quarkusimage

if I try a method with postman I have this result:

addEmployee
Hibernate:
     select
         nextval ('quarkus.hibernate_sequence')
2020-06-18 20: 43: 38,214 WARN [io.agr.pool] (Agroal_20041415421) Datasource '': Connection to localhost: 5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP / IP connections.

if i try to run the application with

docker run --net = "host" -i --rm -p 8080:8080 quarkusimage

the application accesses the database on localhost, but if I try a postman call it can't reach the service.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with docker networking. When an application is run inside `docker`, then `localhost` is **not** the hosts `localhost` **unless** you use `--net = "host"`.

Aside from using `--net = "host"`, you can could use the IP of host instead of `localhost` in the URL.

As for the podman issue you mention, that sounds like a podman bug or limitation - I propose you consult the podman documentation and / or open an issue in the podman issue tracker.